# ngNewRouter in angularjs 1.4.8?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am new to angularjs. 
While I tried learning angularjs using a book (The book was following angularjs 1.3.x, I think), I was taught about configuring routes with help of this module "ngRoute".

Now, I am exploring and trying to understand an angularjs project that follows angularjs 1.4.8. I see this project uses "ngNewRouter". I tried reading couple small write-ups on the internet about the usage of "ngNewRouter" and understand that it was introduced sometime in 1.4.x.

However, when I try exploring documentation (developer guide / api doc) of angularjs 1.4.8, I don't see any mention of "ngNewRouter". Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Angular documentation isn't alwaays 'perfect' :).  Here is a link that might help [NPM Angular New Router](https://angular.github.io/router/getting-started)